# maven include main project into test-jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I have already created a test-jar with the maven-jar-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But the test-jar needs the main classes to work, so how can I include them in the test-jar (creating something like a uber-test-jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add other classes to the test-jar trough the maven-jar-plugin but you can do a jar that contains main project classes and test classes in another way: using the maven-assembly-plugin!

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will create an artifact with the information described in the assembly descriptor, the descriptor default path is src/assembly/.xml
In the descriptor you want to add this:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-  plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>example</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

- id -> postfix to the jar
- format -> format of the output file (we're creating a jar)
- fileSets ->  all the directories to add
- fileSet -> single directory to add, with outputDirectory, include exclude ecc.

this example would create a jar with -example as the postfix (ex: plugin-1.0-example.jar) with both main and test files

Answer (score 1):

Usually I import the dependency twice:

1. The regular one;
2. Test jar with scope = test.

So that you don't have problems with missing classes. However, if you don't need main sources(the first dependency) in your application and they are used only for tests, you can also switch scope of it to test.

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Comment: I don't need to import any classes, I'm only building the jar because I need to test the test-jar as a plug-in in another application

Comment: Hm? The test-jar as a plugin in another application? Sounds wrong to me. I would have expected to test the jar but not the `test-jar`?

Comment: I usually use it, when I need to import some utility test classes from another module. These classes are very useful, and thus they are shared between modules. And the same time, they aren't accessible in main code.