Create uber file from Maven Surefire configuration
The current stack is Maven with modules per domain.
The main module imports the others.
And have a basic spring application on src and a testNG/cucumber/springboot runner on test.
I run that test runner from Surefire and works. Even with threads.
From IDE the same.
How can I create a uber jar with dependencies from that test runner so I can run cucumber features from self sustainable jar?
Tried assembly, jar and shade plug in with several different errors.

Cucumber supports JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) also you can run cucumber with TestNG... why do you like to have a jar file?

Because would like to publish it on Artifactory. And use it on CD/CI pipeline. An allow other to reuse it.

Can you please explain as to what should be in the uber jar for the test runner? I didn't quite understand that part.

Also have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400393/679824

If you have a working build process this will run within the CI/CD pipeline... and usually will not being published upfront...that means via mvn verify (will run also thest unit- and integration tests)

@KrishnanMahadevan the classes under test folders and have an entrypoint of a runner understand test folders as well.

@PauloOliveira - Can you please create a sample project that mimics your current real project, upload it to github and share the link in your question? It would be easier for anyone to suggest changes, if we can see what you currently have.

For me it sounds like you want to create a jar file that contains the classes from the test folder in your module. If that's the case you can just use the maven-jar-plugin to create a test-jar artifact and then add this where ever you need these classes.
Pluginconfiguration to build test-jar artifact:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>  

Include the artifact wherever you need it:
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <version>version</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Also if you have spring-boot-maven-plugin repackaging your main module, it's not possible to use it as a dependency later. Therefore you would need to add a classifier in the spring-boot-maven-plugin to keep the original jar. Here's a description of that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089738/6512438
Reference:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html
